# Unable to create database using prepared statements in MySql

Tags: java, mysql, jdbc, syntax-error, ddl

I am trying to create the database using a prepared statement in MySQL. Here I am passing the parameters as shown.

```java
PreparedStatement createDbStatement = connection.prepareStatement("CREATE DATABASE ?");
createDbStatement.setString(1, "first_database");
createDbStatement.execute();
connection.commit();
```

But I am getting a syntax error. Is it possible to create tables and databases using prepared statements?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

in a `PreparedStatement` can only be used to bind values (e.g., in `where` conditions on in `values` clauses), not object names. Therefore, you cannot use it to bind the name of a database.

You could use string manipulation to add the database name, but in this case, there's really no benefit in using `PreparedStatement`s, and you should just use a `Statement` instead:

```
String dbName = "first_database";
Statement createDbStatement = connection.createStatement();
createDbStatement.execute("CREATE DATABASE " + dbName);
```

Comment: Nice answer, but i have a question; Should `dbName` be validated here manually?

Comment: This is a "skeleton" answer - you should probably add some input sanity/validation here if you get the dbName from user input.

Comment: I know, I just wondered if `Statement.execute()` method does any validation for the input query; or it just sends the query without any validation. Thanks.

Comment: It just sends it to the databsae